# What are the benefits of using a Cloudflare's DNS (not WARP) instead of ISP's DNS?

Tags: privacy, dns, isp, cloudflare

What advantages users get, specifically, from 'PRIVACY' point-of-view?
Can ISP still see and log browsing history? Can user's location be still traceable?
What's the ultimate security & privacy level one can achieve by using Cloudflare's DNS in lieu of ISP's DNS?

Comment: While the DNS service talked about in the question is no Cloudflare, the answers address what you've asked. And you might need to understand where DNS fits in the scheme of things to help you understand its impact.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The introduction of DoH and DoT since the 'dupe' question was written mean that a newer, different answer is available here.

Comment: @gowenfawr even when the 'privacy' component includes tracing the user's location as the context of the question? And that an ISP's DNS can also use DoH and DoT? Yes, there are other benefits to Cloudflare's DNS, but those won't answer what was asked.